# Increment a counter in MySQL every time a product item is viewed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product page in my website that works from a MySQL database, product items are created on the page as a thumbnail picture is clicked on.

Is there any way to increment a MySQL counter every time the thumbnail picture is clicked on?

If there is a way of doing this can someone please point me in the right direction with regards to coding this?

NOTE: this code is working but this update all products hits count. i need update only viewed product items row in table

my mysql table looks like

table name: images

id | product_name | image | price | hits

here is my php code:

---

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("user"); // Selecting Database

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,image,SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',4) as product_name FROM images");

mysql_query("update images set hits = hits+1 where product_name = product_name");

$count = 0;

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
if($count==3) //three images per row
            {
print "</tr>";
$count = 0;
if($count==0)
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";

?>
<?php echo"<div>";?>

<?php echo"<img style='heigth:170px; width:200px'src='image1.php?id=$res[id]'>"?>
<?php echo "<a href=\"getImage.php?id={$res['id']}\">{$res['product_name']}<h3>Read More</h3></a>";?>

<?php echo"</div>";?>

<?php
$count++;
print "
</td>";

}

if($count>0)
print "</tr>";

?>
```

here is getImage.php code`

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<style>
img.floatLeft 
{ 
float: left; 
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 1px; 
padding-left: 2%;
}
p.padding {
padding-left: 2%;
padding-right: 2%;
}

h3 { color:#3300FF; font-family: Slab,Georgia,serif;font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .03em;text-transform: none}

div{background-color: white; border-style: ridge; height: 500px; width: 400px; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;  color: #000000; font: 12px arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;text-align: justify;}

</style>
</HEAD>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("user", $connection); // Selecting Database


$query1 = mysql_query("select * from images where id=$id", $connection);




echo"<div >";

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
echo"<h3 align='center' color='red'>";
echo $row1['product_name'];
echo"</h3>";


echo "<img class='floatLeft'src=image1.php?id=".$row1['id']." width=150 height=140  />";


echo'<p class="padding">';
echo $row1['price'];
echo"</p>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</div>";



?>

<?php
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update it where the ID equals the specific ID of the page they are on. Also you don't need to close the php after every output this whole script can be in one PHP block.

Comment: thanks for answer...but i dont want to count only 1 id...i have many product items in my database each item has id. so want only viewed product item to be counted in database.

Comment: What happens when a use clicks a product image? Do they get redirected to a product page?

Comment: Is this page `getImage.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so on the `/product/product.php` take out the update there because you don't want to update every view count, remove

```
mysql_query("update images set hits = hits+1 where product_name = product_name");
```

Then on the `details.php` page add in

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id']; //the (int) forces this to be a number so you cant be injected
    mysql_query("update images set hits = hits+1 where id = $id");
}
```

You also may want to look at the modulus operator for the `if ($count == 3)`. You also should switch over to using the mysqli or PDO driver.

Comment: The text on that page says View Details and links to details.php. Is that correct? If so where is the getImage.php used or is that an older name?

Comment: YES....I have been trying for last night but still not finished the task....thats why i modified the script for better understanding...

Comment: shall i give you new script ?

Comment: I've posted the updates you should make to your scripts.

Comment: Good Job! Your code is working fine...Thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing any variable to the UPDATE statement. Check the [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Something like this might work

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,image,SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',4) as product_name FROM images");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
mysql_query("update images set hits = hits+1 where product_name = " . $row['product_name']);
```

Also note that `mysql_query` is not the recommended way to access MySQL databases from PHP - see [Choosing a MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['views'])) { 
    $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+1;

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("user"); // Selecting Database

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,image,SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',4) as product_name FROM images");

mysql_query("update images set hits = ".$_SESSION['views']." where product_name = product_name");

$count = 0;

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
if($count==3) //three images per row
            {
print "</tr>";
$count = 0;
if($count==0)
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";

?>
<?php echo"<div>";?>

<?php echo"<img style='heigth:170px; width:200px'src='image1.php?id=$res[id]'>"?>
<?php echo "<a href=\"getImage.php?id={$res['id']}\">{$res['product_name']}<h3>Read More</h3></a>";?>

<?php echo"</div>";?>

<?php
$count++;
print "
</td>";

}

if($count>0)
print "</tr>";
```

Comment: this code showing this eorro...'Parse error: parse error, expecting `']'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\link\products.php on line 32'

Comment: its maybe cause of single quotation that I missed after views], correcting it now.

Comment: @SafinChowdhury - You also must have a value i.e. "0 (zero)" in hits column as update query will be executed and for that there must be some existing value.

Comment: When a user clicks View details. they get redirected to a product page?

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line code (given below) at the end of codes for fetching particular record (before closing the connection)

Code is:

```
$result1 = $conn->query("UPDATE REPLACE_WITH_TABLE_NAME SET views = views + 1 WHERE REPLACE_WITH_CONDITION");
```